Need better proof of SSA congruence of two out of three triangles

If two triangles share SSA and each has an obtuse angle, they are congruent. If two triangles share SSA and neither has an obtuse angle, they are congruent. If either has a right angle, they are congruent. Likewise if three triangles share SSA, then at least two must be congruent.
I have tried to show this last assertion in a high school geometry-style above (without using the law of cosines), but the proof seems very ham-handed. Can anyone help me clean it up of suggest a better way?
